# Google AppEngine server instance clock synchronization

Tags: google-app-engine, synchronization, instance, system-clock

I just came across the following paragraph in the [AppEngine documentation for Query Cursors](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/queries#Java_Cursors_and_data_updates):

> An interesting application of cursors is to monitor entities for
>   unseen changes. If the app sets a timestamp property with the current
>   date and time every time an entity changes, the app can use a query
>   sorted by the timestamp property, ascending, with a Datastore cursor
>   to check when entities are moved to the end of the result list. If an
>   entity's timestamp is updated, the query with the cursor returns the
>   updated entity. If no entities were updated since the last time the
>   query was performed, no results are returned, and the cursor does not
>   move.

For this to work reliably, there would have to be some sort of guarantees about the clock synchronization across different server instances. Otherwise you could get the following scenario:

1. Server instance 1 (fast clock) saves an update with time-stamp 1000.
2. Client asks for updates and finds this one update.
3. Server instance 2 (slow clock) saves another update with time-stamp 950.
4. Client asks for updates and does NOT find this update as time-stamp didn't increase.

As far as I understood, there never were any such clock synchronization guarantees. Did this change???

Update:

I just realized that even if the clocks were sync'ed perfectly, this approach might miss results due to the eventual consistency of queries. If a later update ends up getting committed before an earlier update and makes it into a simultaneous query while the earlier one doesn't, it will hide the earlier update. Or am I missing something?

Comment: I have never found an official statement about clock sync.  on IRC with google folks they said stuff was synced and I believe it however this post from a google dude is probably a good indication of the state of play https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/google-appengine/clock$20sync/google-appengine/XKLp5Uehhr8/MlsdgGwOB-wJ  .  Personally in the early days of appengine I have seen clock skews between instances > 30secs.  Last time I checked I couldn't find any significant skew ;-)

Comment: This is really just a bad example on the docs because there are a lot of edge cases to worry about (like you mentioned). Even with perfect clock sync and strong consistency, setting a timestamp field to now() and when something gets sent to the Datastore could be delayed.

Answer (score 1):

The only docs that i found on clock and Google Cloud Platform, are [here](http://googlecloudplatform.blogspot.ro/2015/05/Got-a-second-A-leap-second-that-is-Be-ready-for-June-30th.html) and [here](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/#configure-ntp).
According to the [first link post](http://googlecloudplatform.blogspot.ro/2015/05/Got-a-second-A-leap-second-that-is-Be-ready-for-June-30th.html), instances are synced using NTP service, and it's done for you.