# Understanding maximum length of an AppEngine key-name in the Java API

Tags: java, google-app-engine, key, maxlength

I am trying to figure out what the maximum length for an AppEngine [key name](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/datastore/Key#getName--) is in the Java API.

This question has been asked in much less depth before:

[How long (max characters) can a datastore entity key_name be? Is it bad to haver very long key_names?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2557632/how-long-max-characters-can-a-datastore-entity-key-name-be-is-it-bad-to-haver)

and received two conflicting answers (with the one that seems less credible to me being the accepted one...)

@ryan was able to provide links to the relevant Python API source in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2557632/how-long-max-characters-can-a-datastore-entity-key-name-be-is-it-bad-to-haver/4813780#4813780) and I've been trying to find something similar in the Java API.

But neither [Key.java](https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/source/browse/trunk/java/src/main/com/google/appengine/api/datastore/Key.java), nor [KeyFactory.java](https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/source/browse/trunk/java/src/main/com/google/appengine/api/datastore/KeyFactory.java), nor [KeyTranslator.java](https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/source/browse/trunk/java/src/main/com/google/appengine/api/datastore/KeyTranslator.java) seem to enforce any limits on the `name` property of a key. So, if there is a limit, it is implemented elsewhere. `KeyTranslator` calls `com.google.storage.onestore.v3.OnestoreEntity.Path.Element.setName()`, which could be the place where the limit is implemented, but unfortunately I can't find the source for this class anywhere...

Specifically, I would like to know:

- Is the 500 character limit a hard limit specifically imposed for key names somewhere in the backend or is it simply a recommendation that *should* be sufficient to make sure the full key-string never exceeds the [1500-byte limit of a short text property](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/entities#Java_Properties_and_value_types) (long text properties with more bytes cannot be indexed, if I understand correctly).
- If it is a hard limit:

  - Is it 500 *characters* or 500 *bytes* (i.e. the length after some encoding)?
  - Are the full 500 bytes/characters available for the name of the key or do the other key-components (kind, parent, app-id, ...) deduct from this number?
- If it is a recommendation:

  - Is it sufficient in all cases?
  - What is the maximum I can use if all keys are located in the root of my application and the kind is only one letter long? In other words: Is there a formula I can use to calculate the *real* limit given the other key components?
- Lastly, if I simply try to measure this limit by attempting to store keys of increasing length until I get some exception, will I be able to rely on the limit that I find if I only create keys with identical ancestor paths and same-length kinds in the same application? Or are there other variable-length components to a key that might get added and reduce the available key-name-length in some cases? Should it be the same for the Development and the Production Servers?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Datastore implements all of its validation in the backend (because it prevents successful operations in one client to fail in another). Datastore keys have the [following restrictions](https://github.com/google/googleapis/blob/master/google/datastore/v1beta3/entity.proto#L54):

- A key can have at most 100 path elements (these are kind, name/id pairs)
- Each kind can be at most 1500 bytes.
- **Each name can be at most 1500 bytes.**

The 500 character limit has been converted into a 1500 byte limit. So places you've seen a 500 character limit before (like @ryan's answer in the linked question) are now 1500 bytes. Strings are encoded using UTF-8.

Importantly to answer some specifics from your question:

> Are the full 500 bytes/characters available for the name of the key or do the other key-components (kind, parent, app-id, ...) deduct from this number?

**No**, the 1500 byte limit is per field.

Comment: Thank you for the in-depth answer! This is great news! It's always good to hear from the source, too. If only I was able to also reach someone on the Android billing team... ;) Mind if I point you to one other (old but still relevant) question of mine about something I believe is a "bug" (or at least unreliable suggestion) in the official documentation? I meanwhile found a work-around, but it might be of interest to you or the person on your team who was working on this topic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18264338/google-appengine-server-instance-clock-synchronization

Comment: Oh, wow! Just found something else important in the linked source: `A name matching regex '__.*__' is reserved/read-only` Good to know!

Comment: hi @Patrick Costello. I still confused with the values. The code above that you shared is about the server API. But on the dependence which is used on Android there is a explicit limitation of 500 chars when creating a key. Isn't that the limitation the question is talking about?